# Angular 5 status of form does not match status of control

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am using Angular 5.1.0.  I am using Reactive Forms.

When I set up the form, I use:

```
this.proposalItemForm = this.fb.group({
    ...
    priceEachControl: [this.proposalItem.priceEach, { updateOn: 'blur', validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*(?:[.][0-9]{2,4})?$")] }],
    ...
});
```

I also set up a data change listener using:

```
this.proposalItemForm.get('priceEachControl').valueChanges.forEach(() => this.changeItem());
```

Here is the function that is called when the priceEachControl value changes:

```
changeItem() {
        console.log(this.proposalItemForm.get("priceEachControl").status);
        // make sure the entire form is valid
        console.log(this.proposalItemForm.status);
        if (this.proposalItemForm.status=="VALID") {
            // first, make sure the data model matches the form model
            this.proposalItem = this.prepareSaveItem();
            // then submit the updated data model to the server
            this.proposalItemService.update(this.proposalItem).subscribe(
              data => {
                  this.proposalItem = data;
              },
              error => {
                  if (error.exception=="EntityNotFoundException") {
                      this.messagesService.error(error.message);
                  }
                  else {
                    this.messagesService.error("There was a problem updating the proposal item.");
                    console.error("Error: ", error);
                  }
              },
              () => {}
            );
        }
    }
```

The updateOn feature seems to work correctly, as it does not call `changeItem()` on every keystroke, but only when I leave the field.

The problem is that the status is not always correct.  For example, let's say that the priceEach = 9.7 when the form is loaded. That is an INVALID value. (Per the regex, if a decimal point is present, there must be 2 to 4 numbers after the decimal point.) If I change it to 9.75 (a VALID value), in the console output I see

```
VALID
INVALID
```

and the service is not called.  However, if I change it back to 9.7 (INVALID), then it outputs

```
INVALID
VALID
```

and calls the service.

I know that it is not a problem with my regex because clearly the status of the control itself is correct.  Further, if I put multiple values in that are valid, then the form status is valid as expected.  The problem only occurs when switching from a valid to an invalid state or vice versa.

How can I make sure that the form status is using the values which were just input, so that the form status matches the control status?  When does the form status get updated after a control changes?

Comment: The flow is: control get updated -> control's events fired -> parent group get updated -> parent group's events fired. It'll always be lagging behind if you subscribe to the control event like that.

Answer (score 2):

This line just looks at the current status
  if (this.proposalItemForm.status=="VALID")

You should hook onto the statusChanges observable

```
this.proposalItemForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
     if (status=="VALID")
       //logic here             
     });
```

Like so..

```
this.proposalItemForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
        if (status == "VALID") {
            // first, make sure the data model matches the form model
            this.proposalItem = this.prepareSaveItem();
            // then submit the updated data model to the server
            this.proposalItemService.update(this.proposalItem).subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.proposalItem = data;
                },
                error => {
                    if (error.exception == "EntityNotFoundException") {
                        this.messagesService.error(error.message);
                    } else {
                        this.messagesService.error(
                            "There was a problem updating the proposal item."
                        );
                        console.error("Error: ", error);
                    }
                },
                () => {}
            );
        }
    });
```